# What are the differences between wireless gaming adapters and straight wireless adapters?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, xbox360

Devices like the Xbox - with only an ethernet port and no built-in wireless - can be connected to wireless networks using a gaming adapter.  How does a gaming adapter differ from a regular wireless adapter?

Answer (score 2):

The gaming adapter and the wireless adapter are the same thing.  802.11 Wireless on one end and network type "X" on the other end.  This is called a [network bridge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-a-network-bridge).

Comment: I was thinking about this more.  The gaming adapter is indeed a bridge (it knows nothing about IP except perhaps for configuration purposes), as the IP address would be on the Xbox's ethernet adapter when connected to a gaming adapter.  But a wireless network adapter *is* the device that gets the IP address itself, eg it is analogous to the Xbox's ethernet port in this case.  And the wireless adapter doesn't have a network on both sides, it has a PC bus/usb port on one side and the wireless on the other.  Am I getting this right?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Keltari's answer, most wireless adapters that are marketed as "gaming adapters" feature Automatic Quality of Service (QoS), which is essentially like a priority lane for your gaming console's traffic. It reduces the TCP priority of other traffic, so you get the best performance possible from your connection. If you are interested, [here is a decent article](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service) about QoS.

Most decent routers allow you to set up your own QoS anyway, so [if your console was supported] you could set your own priority traffic. The gaming adapter just does this automatically. This is how they get away with marketing as "a lag-free gaming experience", which is not necessarily true. It will only be lag-free if your network is not bogged down entirely by other traffic, and the network has a high enough throughput in the first place to support the game you are playing.